# How can I prevent Docker from removing intermediate containers when executing RUN command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

The error I'm experiencing is that I want to execute the command "change directory" in my Docker machine, but every time I execute RUN instruction in my Dockerfile, it deletes the actual container (intermediate container).

***DOCKERFILE***

[image]

This happens when I execute the Dockerfile from above

[image]

How can I prevent Docker from doing that?

Comment: It seems like you've attached some non-runnable images to your question instead of your Dockerfile.  Can you replace these images with the actual text of your Dockerfile, and the actual text of the output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current paths are different for Dockerfile and *RUN* (inside container).

Each *RUN* command starts from the Dockerfile path (e. g. '/').

When you do `RUN cd /app`, the "inside path" changes, but not the "Dockerfile path". The next *RUN* command will again be run at '/'.

To change the "Dockerfile path", use *WORKDIR* (see [reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir)), for example `WORKDIR /opt/firefox`.

The alternative would be chaining the executed *RUN* commands, as EvgeniySharapov pointed out: `RUN cd opt; ls; cd firefox; ls`

on multiple lines:

```
RUN cd opt; \
    ls; \
    cd firefox; \
    ls
```

(To clarify: It doesn't matter that Docker removes intermediate containers, that is not the problem in this case.)

Answer (score 11):

`docker build --rm=false`

Remove intermediate containers after a successful build (default true)

Answer (score 4):

When you use `docker build --no-cache` this will delete intermediate containers when you build an image. This may affect building times when you run `build` multiple times. Alternatively you can choose to put multiple shell commands into one shell command using `\`  and then use it as a `RUN` argument.
Mote tips could be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)